# Задача сравнить файл с эталонным и вывести только те строки, которые отсутствовали в эталоне

Tags: python

Есть 2 файла (логов): один эталонный, другой исходный. В файлах построчно записаны пути ко всем файлам за всю историю хранилища. Все строки каждого файла неупорядочены. Задача сравнить исходный лог с эталонным на поиск соответствующей строки, и, если соответствия не обнаружено, выводить исключённую строку построчно в новый файл.

Задача невероятно лёгкая, но я всегда испытываю проблему нехватки памяти при решении задачи в лоб рекурсивным циклом for, либо возникает странная ошибка что в какой-то момент у списка пытаются взять несуществующий элемент (контролировать и тем более дебажить рекурсию я пока не умею)

Как решить эту задачу используя минимум рекурсии?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем вам вообще рекурсия, если вы можете воспользоваться множествами?

```
f1 = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
f2 = ["aaa", "bbb", "ddd", "ccc"]
print(set(f2)-set(f1))
#{'ddd'}
```

Разумеется, могут существовать разумные ограничения по количеству обрабатываемой информации, но попробовать стоит.